# How to create a web form allowing authenticated users to upload files to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

How to create a web application that takes user inputs and stores image files uploaded by authorized users to AWS? The users who have permission to upload files are web users, not AWS IAM users. Ideally, they access this web from a url with query parameter representing this authorized user. I am thinking about creating a static website in S3, storing user input and image files in a S3 bucket subfolder. Each authorized user only have read\write permission to its own subfolder. However, since S3 is serverless, I need details on how to use lambda and API Gateway or other AWS services to process request from web form and upload files to S3. It seems like I can use Drupal or WordPress Webform plugin to create the webform and upload files to S3. In this case, I need a EC2 instance for Drupal\WordPress instead of a S3 static website. I am looking for suggestions on the best architecture for this project. Any tutorials, instructions, and sample codes are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are require your users to authenticate against you application, then you need to store their credentials in some database (i.e DynamoDB). To do that, you need some back-end service that will perform authentication process - store users' credentials in a DB, retrieve users's credentials from DB, verify credentials.

You can either write your own server, or go with serverless Lambda approach with API Gateway. But the important thing here is that you need to have this back-end logic. There is no way to achieve it using only static S3 web hosting (but it can be part of the overall system).

AWS IAM is used in this scenario only to create role that allows service - EC2/Lambda - to perform read/write operation on the S3 bucket and DynamoDB. Your application users have nothing to do with IAM.

Flow of the application would be:

1. user signs up to your application
2. your application creates a record in a DB with the user credentials and pointer to some S3 resource that will be unique to this user
3. when signed in user tries to upload image the data is sent to your application
4. your application retrieves requester's record from DB, looks for the S3 pointer and upload the image there

From the architectural perspective, there is a lot of factors to take into consideration when designing such system - amount of traffic, requirements on CI-CD an such.

If you want something pretty simple, then you can create your REST API using API Gateway, where each resource-method will have appropriate lambda function assigned to it (these function will perform the above mentioned logic). You can use a custom authentication processes or you can leverage AWS Congnito. Finally, you can host your webpage (assuming that it is static in this setup) on S3 making ajax calls against your API gateway.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to achieve this without server or lambda function,  Just using Cognito and the AWS SDK for Javascript

Comment: Thank you for your feedback so much.  For this project, the web users will login to this app through the password they provided during sign up rather than using their OpenID credentials.  How to retrieve user password stored in mySQL DB in one EC2 WordPress instance programatically and use it to authenticate user login to the app that allowing users to upload files to its own S3 subfolder?  I am new to AWS, any sample code or tutorials to make it work is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/).  [Cognito Federated Identities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html) allows to vend temporary access tokens to authenticated users.  It integrates with Login With Amazon, Facebook, Google or anything that speaks OpenID or SAML.

Your Singe Page Web app can access Cognito through the [AWS SDK for Javascript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/index.html).

So the idea is to propose an authentication on your web page.  I am using [Login with Amazon](https://login.amazon.com/) or similar.  You can also choose to use Cognito User Pool (where Cognito stores user profiles and provides signin, signup, password recovery etc)

Once authenticated, your Javascript code can call `refresh()` on `AWS.Config.credentials`, passing the access token received from the authentication step above.  `refresh()` will, in turn, call Cognito's API to receive a temporary and user specific access token.

```
function initializeCognito(access_token) {

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
                AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
                AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:cognito pool id', // < -- insert your cognito pool ID here
                    Logins: {
                        'www.amazon.com': access_token
                    }
                });
                console.log("Calling Cognito to refresh AWS Credentials");

                // get AWS credentials
                AWS.config.credentials.refresh(function (err) {

                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error when calling Cognito");
                        console.log(err, err.stack);
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Cognito credenials received ");
                        resolve(AWS.config.credentials);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Once this is done, the rest of your code can call any AWS SDK API to call backend services, incl S3, DynamoDB ...

Here is an example for DynamoDB :

```
        function insertIntoDDB(profile, text) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
                var params = {
                    Item: {
                        "cognitoid": { //hash key
                            S: profile.cognito_id
                        },
                        "userid": {
                            S: profile.user_id
                        },
                        "text": {
                            S: text
                        },
                        "creationtime": { // sort key 
                            N: Math.round(new Date() / 1000).toString()
                        },
                        "expirationtime": { // 1 month later ?
                            N: (Math.round(new Date() / 1000) + (1 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)).toString()
                        }
                    },
                    TableName: "my_table"
                };
                dynamodb.putItem(params, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error when calling DynamoDB");
                        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        // console.log(data); // successful response
                        resolve(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

The AWS SDK manages the authentication for you, as you can see, there is no code involved to pass an access key, secret key.  The access key and secret key is generated for that specific user by Cognito and stored in `AWS.config.credential` object.  The access key and secret key is limited in scope and limited in time.

To limit the scope, on the Cognito console, you define the IAM role to associate with authenticated users, granting them the permissions to access only the services and operations required by your code.  In addition, S3 and DynamoDB allows for [fine grained permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html), allowing you to restrict write access to specific keys (folder) in your bucket or row in your table.

You can see this technique in action at https://alexademo.ninja/skills/myteacher/index.html  I wrote this to work with the "[My Pronunciation Teacher](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078VH3QM6)" Alexa Skill.

There is also a full tutorial that will show you how to use the AWS SDK for JavaScript to upload pictures from a web form to S3 in the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html). This code also leverage's Cognito and it's quite close to what you want to achieve.

Using this technique, no backend server is required.